# How to create a new DataMapper type?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I was following the guide from the [DataMapper site](http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types), and this is what I have:

```
module DataMapper
    class Property
        class SymbolStore < String
            def dump(v)
                v.to_s
            end

            def load(v)
                v.to_sym
            end

            def typcast_to_primitive(v)
                v.to_s
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But, I'm getting strange behaviour. When I try to set a value that is a SymbolStore, it comes back as a string. However, if I load a record, it comes back properly, as a symbol. From my experiments, `load` only seems to be called when a record is loaded, and not when I'm trying to get the value of something I've just set.

In the real world, I should not need to get a value I have just set, but this problem does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `typecast_to_primitive` (you had a typo).